# is there a list of mitzvos which show respect?

Tags: taamei-mitzvot-reasons

I'm looking for a list of Mitzvos which show how important respect is. I have a few, but would like to know all others.

The ones I have are:

Kibud av ve'eim
Mipnei seiva takum

Comment: This question would be more compelling if you could [edit] in why you want this information. It would also be easier for people to give you precisely what you need if you define more precisely what you mean by "respect."

Comment: You have asked for mitzvos which show the importance of respect but the two examples you give, and which have been followed by some of the answers, are about honor. Which do you want? (To clarify what I mean, we should respect all/most people, but only a few are we required to honor).

Comment: @Loewian, could you please not flood the front page by editing a bunch of questions to add/change a tag?  It pushes other recently-asked (or recently-active) questions out of view before they've had a chance to be seen. Yes there are other ways to see them, but as a kindness to people looking for answers to new questions, let's try to keep edits like this down to ~10 at a time, ok?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The Rambam's [ספר המצוות](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01550.html) lists the following Mitzvo with the word *respect* in them:

> **מצוה כב**. היא שצונו לשמור **המקדש** וללכת סביבו תמיד **לכבדו** ולרוממו ולגדלו, ‏

To honour the Bet HaMikdash.

> **מצוה לב**. היא שצונו **לכבד זרע אהרן** לפארם ולנשאם‏

To honour the Cohanim of priestly descent.

> **מצוה לג**. היא שצוה הכהנים ללבוש **בגדים** מיוחדים **לכבוד** ולתפארת ואז יעבדו במקדש ‏

The Cohen weares special clothes to be respectable in the Bet HaMikdash.

> **מצוה סח**: שהזהיר כהן הגדול מהכנס למקדש בכל עת מפני **כבוד** המקדש וגדולתו‏

The Cohen Gadol - out of respect - does not enter the Bet HaMikdash for no reason.

> **מצוה רט**. היא שצונו **לכבד החכמים** ולקום מפניהם

Respect the wise ones.

> **מצוה רי**. היא שצונו **לכבד אב ואם**. ‏

Respect parents.

> **מצוה רעה**: שהזהיר הדיין **שלא לכבד אחד מבעלי הריב** בענין הדין ואפילו היה גדול ונכבד ונשוא פנים לא יסביר לו פנים בדין כשיבא לפניו‏

A Bet Din - in session - must not show respect to either party, even if he deserves such respect.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a mitzva to honor Shabbos, as the Navi Yeshaya (58:13) says אִם תָּשִׁיב מִשַּׁבָּת רַגְלֶךָ עֲשׂוֹת חֲפָצֶיךָ בְּיוֹם קָדְשִׁי וְקָרָאתָ לַשַּׁבָּת עֹנֶג לִקְדוֹשׁ יְהוָה מְכֻבָּד וְכִבַּדְתּוֹ מֵעֲשׂוֹת דְּרָכֶיךָ מִמְּצוֹא חֶפְצְךָ וְדַבֵּר דָּבָר.

Answer (score 0):

- Kavod Hamet - Honoring the dead - Rambam mentions this aas a mitzvah, but I couldn't locate these exact words in Mishnah Torah / Hilchot Avel. Perhaps, someone can edit in here.
- Kavod Hatzibbur - Respect for the congregation - mentioned in a few places in Shulchan Aruch. This is mentioned as the main reason as to why women are not called to read from the Torah in the synagogue.
- Kavod Habri'ot - respect for other (living) people. Have to research the origin of this halacha

Comment: Is kavod habriot exclusive of the honoring the dead? And is it exclusive of non-people? I thought this was much broader (but usually only applied to other living people).